# SQL: How do I add different columns from different tables and make it one amount?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to add columns from different tables in order to get a total amount of all my streams. I've tried joining `SQL JOIN` them which works fine but it doesn't allow me to get the total number of streams. I've now decided to use union `SQL UNION` all but I still can't get the total number of streams. How do I go about doing getting a final amount after concatenating these tables. the solution that I got from previous questions here on stack overflow don't seem to work as well.

```
from http.client import OK
from logging import exception
import psycopg
import pandas as pd

dbname = '******' 
user ='******'
password = '*******' 
host = '**********' 
port = **** 
conn = None

try:
    with psycopg.connect(
        dbname = dbname,
        user = user,
        password = password,
        host = host, 
        port = port 
    ) as conn:

        with conn.cursor() as cur:

            total_streaming_plays = '''SELECT artist, SUM(plays) AS total_plays
            FROM SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify
            UNION ALL
            SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_tidal
            UNION ALL
            SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_soundcloud
            UNION ALL
            SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube
            UNION ALL
            SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube_music
            GROUP BY artist;'''

            cur.execute(total_streaming_plays) 
            for records in cur:
                print(records)   

        conn.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

output

```
syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 2:             FROM SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `()`

```
SELECT artist, SUM(plays) AS total_plays
            FROM (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_tidal)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_soundcloud)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube_music)
            GROUP BY artist;
```

I think this will address the error, but I don't think it's a good practice, I would prefer using `With AS` .

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_tidal)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_soundcloud)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube_music)
)
SELECT artist, SUM(plays) AS total_plays
FROM temp
```

All in all, it is too hard to give suggestion without sample data.

Comment: this worked thanx, but I removed the ````SELECT artist```` statement at the end and used ````SUM(plays) AS from temp```` for it to work properly.

Comment: Yes, in order to use sum with other column, you have to use `GROUP BY <column name>`